# Copy mutiple sheet in one single with the name of the sheet in the first column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy multiple sheets in one single and I use this script that put all data from the second column (B).
How I can put the name of every sheet in the first column (A)?

```
Public Sub m()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shStorico As Worksheet
Dim lng As Long
Dim lRiga As Long

Set shStorico = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATI")

With shStorico
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            lRiga = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Range("A2:E200").Copy
            .Range("B" & lRiga + 1).PasteSpecial

    Next
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set sh = Nothing
Set shStorico = Nothing

End Sub
```

Example

[image]

UPDATE

This is the solution that works

```
Public Sub m()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shStorico As Worksheet
Dim lng As Long
Dim lRiga As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range, rArea As Range
Dim iRow As Long

Set shStorico = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATI")
With shStorico
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lRiga = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Range("A2:D2000").Copy
        .Range("B" & lRiga + 1).PasteSpecial
        .Range("A" & lRiga + 1).Value = sh.Name
    Next sh
    iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range("A2").Resize(iRow - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng2 = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In Rng2.Areas
            With rArea
                .Value = .Cells(1).Offset(-1).Value
            End With
        Next rArea
    End If
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set sh = Nothing
Set shStorico = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code currently run as expected? You would just need to put `sh.Name` in column A of the `shStorico` sheet.  Do you want the `copy` to run on `shStorico` too? Or should the loop skip that one?

Comment: @BruceWayne the code work perfectly...I need only to add a line of code(I think), so to have in the first cell of each row the name of the sheet from which it was copied

Comment: `.Range("A" & lRiga + 1).Value = sh.Name` ?

Comment: @BruceWayne this work but put the name only on the first row copied for each sheet, I need to put the name of the sheet in every row copied

Comment: I updated the post with the solution that works)